# Java newbie here. Can someone point out why my output is always $0.0

Tags: java

This is what I have written. I have referred mostly to Java's guide on if ... if else statements and can't pinpoint the reason why the return value is always $0.0.

```
public class Ass1b
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Importing two scanner classes for Text and Number inputs
        Scanner inText = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inNumber = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Declaration of variables
        String taxPayerName;
        int taxPayerIncome;
        double tax = 0;

        //Message prompt asking user to enter a tax payers name and storing the input into the assigned String object
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the tax payer ==> ");
        taxPayerName = inText.nextLine();

        //Message prompt asking the user to enter the tax payers income and storing the input into the assigned Interger variable
        System.out.print("Enter the income for " + taxPayerName + " ==> " );
        taxPayerIncome = inNumber.nextInt();

        if (taxPayerIncome > 18200) {
            tax = 0;
        } else if (taxPayerIncome > 37000) {
            tax = (taxPayerIncome - 18200) * 0.19;
        } else if (taxPayerIncome > 87000) {
            tax = 3572 + (taxPayerIncome - 37000) * 0.325;
        } else if (taxPayerIncome > 180000) {
            tax = 19822 + (taxPayerIncome - 87000) * 0.37;
        } else {
            tax = 54232 + (taxPayerIncome - 180000) * 0.47;
        }


        //Message prompt stating the amount of tax the tax payer owes
        System.out.println("The tax that " + taxPayerName + " has to pay is $" + tax);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your calculations are done in int and then translated to double. in int 0.x is 0. You need to explicitly make double calculation.

Comment: 370000 is greater than 18200 so the if is true

Comment: Try to debug it. Check which `if else` block is being executed.

Comment: @MohammedAtif that is wrong, multiplying an int by a double results in a double. There is another problem here. The if statements are in the wrong order.

Comment: please check your expressions, the first expression will true if the taxPayerIncome input is >18200 regardless of it is >37000 or >87000 or >180000. It's logic error.

Comment: I highly recommend Eric Lippert's "[How To Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" for advice on isolating bugs like this one.  It's one of several good articles listed at the bottom of the Help Center's "[ask]".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it by flipping the > to a <. Whoops!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `if...else` code block. If there taxPayerIncome is anywhere above `18200` the first `if` will trigger. Even if the value is above `37000` or `87000` the first `if` will get it.

Only the last `else` clause is also important as it will get all values below `18200`. But because of the low taxPayerIncome it will return very low values.

Answer (score 0):

you should modify your if expressions like this

```
  if (taxPayerIncome > 18200 && taxPayerIncome < =37000) {
        tax = 0;
    } else if (taxPayerIncome > 37000 && taxPayerIncome <=87000) {
        tax = (taxPayerIncome - 18200) * 0.19;
    } 
 ///and so on..
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it doesn't: If you enter a number that is <=18200, you receive a value other than 0.0.

You have to look at your if-statements: If you enter (for example) 37001, you still enter the first if, since your number is greater than 18200. Therefore, your tax becomes 0.0

In order to change that, use

```
if (taxPayerIncome > 18200 && taxPayerIncome <= 37000)
```

You have to adapt all your if-statements!

Another shorter and more readable way would be to rearrange your ifs:

```
if (taxPayerIncome > 180000) {
    //calc
} else if (taxPayerIncome > 87000) {
    //calc
} else if (taxPayerIncome > 37000) {
    //calc
} else if (taxPayerIncome > 18200) {
    //calc
} else { //below 18200
    //calc
}
```

Comment: Better yet, reverse the order.